# How do you input this emoticon in Facebook messages?

Tags: facebook

I'm using Firefox 35.0.1 and having trouble inserting this emoticon:

[image]

It doesn't appear in the emoticon list:

[image]

So my only option has been copying it from an [external website](http://www.symbols-n-emoticons.com/p/facebook-emoticons-list.html). Is that what everyone else is doing, or is there a shortcut I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can download this extension for Firefox, which requires no restart:

[Facebook Secret Emoticons 3.3.2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/facebook-secret-emoticons/)

It's well reviewed & has a good user base. I've personally given it a shot and it unlocks a whole bunch of other emoji's, the one you mentioned included.